# Downloading YouTube video information, used to work, now not so much

Tags: vb.net, youtube

I used to have some code for downloading youtube data and processing it and everything worked fine until google changed something.  Was around the time they changed it from 1 channel per account to as many as you want.
This is a sample of the feed that I would download and process but I can’t seem to get it working.

```
    feedUrl = http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads
```

The code I would use to process it looks like this;

```
    Dim videoFeed As Feed(Of Video) = request.[Get](Of Video)(New Uri(feedUrl))
```

In the references section, I used to have v2.1 of the google.GData.YouTube, .Extensions & .Client addons and I have updated them to 2.2.

I tried changing the code that processes the line to this but it still doesn’t work.

```
    Dim videoFeed As Feed(Of Google.YouTube.Video) = request.[Get](Of Google.YouTube.Video)(New Uri(feedUrl))
```

The code runs over the line ok, it’s when it tries to use videoFeed, it throws the error.

```
    intTotalVideos = videoFeed.TotalResults
```

The error I get is as follows;

```
    Execution of request failed: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads
```

I don’t know what changed on the google side, maybe it was the new v3 API or the way you log in via code changed when they let you have multiple channels per account.

If anyone has any advice or where I can find more information, it would be greatly appreciated.
(I tried to find the original code on the net that I used to create the project but was unable to find it sorry.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Developer's Guide: .NET](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet):

> The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March
>   4, 2014. Please refer to our deprecation policy for more information.

The following V2 example works for me:

```
Dim settings As New YouTubeRequestSettings(applicationName, developerKey)
Dim request As New YouTubeRequest(settings)
Dim videoFeed As Feed(Of Video) = request.[Get](Of Video)(New Uri(feedUrl))
Dim intTotalVideos As Integer = videoFeed.TotalResults
```

[Google YouTube SDK](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/detail?name=Google_Data_API_Setup_2.2.0.0.msi&can=2&q=) .Net Library with version **2.2.0** is used.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Your code works on my machine so it must be the part where I pass the username and password.  I have;

    Dim settings As New YouTubeRequestSettings(applicationName, developerKey, UserName, password)

Do you know if google changed what parameters you send in?  I used to be able to use the username and password I use when logging in via a web page but since they added the whole google plus stuff, its got a bit confusing...
If you have 2 channels per youtube account, how does the code above know which channel to get the videos from?

Comment: Since every YouTube channel is guaranteed to have a unique channel ID associated with it, you could specify channel ID as described here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids